Volume Calc, I want to select a part of a mesh and then calculate the volume
I have a mesh, originally it was a point cloud
Its basically a photo from above, of a mine with stockpiles.
I want to select the stockpiles individually and calculate their volumes one by one, I tried using the 3d Print addon, but it keeps showing the volume of the entire map instead of the selected verts i have
I tried splitting them from the original mesh, But it keeps displaying the volume of the entire map. any help?
-Josh
